# Get absolute coordinates of point from scene with anchorPoint of (0.5, 0.5)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What's the right way to convert a point into absolute coordinates if the containing scene has an `anchorPoint` of (0.5, 0.5)? Conceptually, we set the anchorPoint to (0.5, 0.5) and then add a child with position (0, 0). Assuming the device is a 5S, the conversion should yield (160, 240).

We're using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `SKNode` on your Scene. Then set its position rely on the scene's frame. Sample Code here:

```
    var node = SKNode()
    node.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)
    node.position = CGPointMake(-scene.frame.width/2, -scene.frame.height/2)
    scene.addChild(node)
```

Add your sprite on this node, you now can get the absolute position~

Comment: I am struggling with a similar probleme, and i though about this solution; but the second problem is: SKNode doesn't have anchorPoint property

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW45) provided with SKNode to get relative points in the node tree.

```
convertPoint:toNode:  
convertPoint:fromNode:
```

Using Carrl's method above to add an SKNode, you can get absolute points as follows:

```
var relativeNode = SKNode()
relativeNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0)
relativeNode.position = CGPointMake(-scene.frame.width/2, -scene.frame.height/2)
scene.addChild(relativeNode)

var absolutePoint = scene.convertPoint(someNode.position, toNode: relativeNode)    
//This will result in {160, 240} on a 5S.
```

These methods take into consideration the various anchorPoints of the nodes.